# Stack Overflow like pager

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on a Stack Overflow like pager for my personal use and I've gotten everything working pretty good.  Some of my logic is a bit suspect though, especially the logic in the Pager class itself.  I thought I'd try posting this code on here just to see what sort of responses I got.  I included my test cases as well.  Some of the test names might be weird, but I'll go back and fix that later.

```
  public class Pager {
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
    public int SelectedItem { get; private set; }
    public int PageNumbersToShow { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    public Pager(int selectedItem, int totalPages, int pageNumbersToShow = 5) {
      this.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
      this.TotalPages = totalPages;
      this.PageNumbersToShow = pageNumbersToShow;
      this.CssClass = "pager fl";
    }

    public override string ToString() {
      var finalString = new StringBuilder();
      var pagerDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
      pagerDiv.AddCssClass(CssClass);

      //prev 1 2 (3)
      //prev 1 (2) 3 next
      // (1) 2 3 next
      if (TotalPages <= PageNumbersToShow) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++) {
          finalString.Append(new PageNumber(i, (SelectedItem == i)).ToString());
        }

      }

      //Greater than pagesize and selected page is less than pagesize
      // prev (1) 2 3 4 5 ... 11 next
      // prev  1 (2) 3 4 5 ... 11 next
      if (SelectedItem < PageNumbersToShow && TotalPages > PageNumbersToShow) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= PageNumbersToShow; i++) {
          finalString.Append(new PageNumber(i, (SelectedItem == i)).ToString());
        }
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber().ToString());
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber(TotalPages).ToString());

      }

      //prev 1 ... 7 8 9 10 (11)
      //prev 1 ... 7 (8) 9 10 11 next
      if (SelectedItem > PageNumbersToShow && TotalPages - (PageNumbersToShow - 1) < SelectedItem) {

        finalString.Append(new PageNumber(1).ToString());
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber().ToString());
        for (int i = (TotalPages - PageNumbersToShow) + 1; i <= TotalPages; i++) {
          finalString.Append(new PageNumber(i, (SelectedItem == i)).ToString());
        }

      }

      //prev 1 ... 4 5 (6) 7 8 ... 11 next
      if (SelectedItem >= PageNumbersToShow && TotalPages - (PageNumbersToShow - 1) >= SelectedItem) {

        finalString.Append(new PageNumber(1).ToString());
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber().ToString());
        var middle = (PageNumbersToShow / 2);
        for (int i = SelectedItem - middle; i <= SelectedItem + middle; i++) {
          finalString.Append(new PageNumber(i, (SelectedItem == i)).ToString());
        }
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber().ToString());
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber(TotalPages).ToString());

      }

      /* Add Previous and Next Link */
      if (SelectedItem != 1) {
        finalString.Insert(0, new PageNumber(SelectedItem - 1, "prev").ToString());
      }
      if (SelectedItem != TotalPages) {
        finalString.Append(new PageNumber(SelectedItem + 1, "next").ToString());
      }

      /* Copy final string into div inner HTML */
      pagerDiv.InnerHtml = finalString.ToString();

      return pagerDiv.ToString();

    }

    private class PageNumber {
      private const string cssClass = "page-numbers";
      private const string href = "?page={0}";
      private TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
      private TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
      public bool Current { get; private set; }
      public int Page { get; private set; }


      public PageNumber(int Page, bool Current = false) {
        this.Current = Current;
        this.Page = Page;
        span.AddCssClass(cssClass);
        span.SetInnerText(Page.ToString());
      }

      public PageNumber(int Page, string spanText) {
        this.Page = Page;
        span.AddCssClass(cssClass + " " + spanText);
        span.SetInnerText(spanText + " ");
      }

      public PageNumber() {
        span.AddCssClass(cssClass + " " + "dots");
        span.SetInnerText("...");
      }

      public override string ToString() {
        if (Current) {
          span.AddCssClass("current");
          return span.ToString();
        } else {

          if (span.ToString().Contains("dots")) {
            return span.ToString();
          }

          link.MergeAttribute("href", string.Format(href, Page));
          link.MergeAttribute("title", string.Format("go to page {0}", Page));
          link.InnerHtml = span.ToString();
          return link.ToString();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  [TestClass]
  public class PagerTests {
    // (1)
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Only_Print_Out_One_Span_If_Number_Of_Pages_Is_One() {

      //Arrange
      var pager = new Pager(1, 1);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      result.ShouldEqual(@"<div class=""pager fl""><span class=""current page-numbers"">1</span></div>");
    }

    // (1) 2 3 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Not_Print_Out_Previous_If_Selected_Page_Is_First_In_List_Smaller_Than_Five() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(1, 3);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">1</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=2"" title=""go to page 2""><span class=""page-numbers"">2</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=3"" title=""go to page 3""><span class=""page-numbers"">3</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=2"" title=""go to page 2""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());
    }

    // prev 1 2 (3)
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Not_Print_Out_Next_Link_When_Selected_Page_Is_Last_In_List_Smaller_Than_Five() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(3, 3);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=2"" title=""go to page 2""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=2"" title=""go to page 2""><span class=""page-numbers"">2</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">3</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());
    }

    // prev 1 (2) 3 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Print_Out_Both_Next_And_Previous_When_Selected_Is_Not_First_Or_Last_In_List_Smaller_Than_Five() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(2, 3);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">2</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=3"" title=""go to page 3""><span class=""page-numbers"">3</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=3"" title=""go to page 3""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());
    }

    // (1) 2 3 4 5 ... 11 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void List_Greater_Than_Five_Pages_Generates_Dot_Dot_Dot_Last_Link_With_Page_One_Selcted() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(1, 11);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">1</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=2"" title=""go to page 2""><span class=""page-numbers"">2</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=3"" title=""go to page 3""><span class=""page-numbers"">3</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=4"" title=""go to page 4""><span class=""page-numbers"">4</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=5"" title=""go to page 5""><span class=""page-numbers"">5</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=11"" title=""go to page 11""><span class=""page-numbers"">11</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=2"" title=""go to page 2""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());

    }

    // prev 1 ... 3 4 (5) 6 7 ... 11 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void List_Greater_Than_Five_Give_Prev_One_Dot_Dot_Dot_Four_Numbers_Dot_Dot_Dot_Last_Next() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(5, 11);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=4"" title=""go to page 4""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=3"" title=""go to page 3""><span class=""page-numbers"">3</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=4"" title=""go to page 4""><span class=""page-numbers"">4</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">5</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=6"" title=""go to page 6""><span class=""page-numbers"">6</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=7"" title=""go to page 7""><span class=""page-numbers"">7</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=11"" title=""go to page 11""><span class=""page-numbers"">11</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=6"" title=""go to page 6""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());

    }

    // prev 1 ... 7 8 9 10 (11)
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_List_Is_Greater_Than_Five_And_Selected_Is_The_Last_Item() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(11, 11);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=10"" title=""go to page 10""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=7"" title=""go to page 7""><span class=""page-numbers"">7</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=8"" title=""go to page 8""><span class=""page-numbers"">8</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=9"" title=""go to page 9""><span class=""page-numbers"">9</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=10"" title=""go to page 10""><span class=""page-numbers"">10</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">11</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());

    }

    // prev 1 ... 7 (8) 9 10 11 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_List_Is_Greater_Than_Five_And_Within_PageSize_Of_End_Of_List_And_Last_Item_Is_Not_Selected() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(8, 11);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=7"" title=""go to page 7""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=7"" title=""go to page 7""><span class=""page-numbers"">7</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">8</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=9"" title=""go to page 9""><span class=""page-numbers"">9</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=10"" title=""go to page 10""><span class=""page-numbers"">10</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=11"" title=""go to page 11""><span class=""page-numbers"">11</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=9"" title=""go to page 9""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());

    }

    //prev 1 ... 5 6 (7) 8 9 ... 11 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_Selected_Is_One_Less_Than_Page_Size() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(7, 11);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=6"" title=""go to page 6""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=5"" title=""go to page 5""><span class=""page-numbers"">5</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=6"" title=""go to page 6""><span class=""page-numbers"">6</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">7</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=8"" title=""go to page 8""><span class=""page-numbers"">8</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=9"" title=""go to page 9""><span class=""page-numbers"">9</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=11"" title=""go to page 11""><span class=""page-numbers"">11</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=8"" title=""go to page 8""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());

    }

    //prev 1 ... 8 9 (10) 11 12 ... 15 next
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_Selected_Is_Exactly_Total_Pages_Minus_Page_Size() {

      //Arrange
      StringBuilder expectedValue = new StringBuilder();
      var pager = new Pager(10, 15);

      //Act
      var result = pager.ToString();

      //Assert
      expectedValue.Append(@"<div class=""pager fl"">");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=9"" title=""go to page 9""><span class=""page-numbers prev"">prev </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=1"" title=""go to page 1""><span class=""page-numbers"">1</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=8"" title=""go to page 8""><span class=""page-numbers"">8</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=9"" title=""go to page 9""><span class=""page-numbers"">9</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""current page-numbers"">10</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=11"" title=""go to page 11""><span class=""page-numbers"">11</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=12"" title=""go to page 12""><span class=""page-numbers"">12</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<span class=""page-numbers dots"">...</span>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=15"" title=""go to page 15""><span class=""page-numbers"">15</span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"<a href=""?page=11"" title=""go to page 11""><span class=""page-numbers next"">next </span></a>");
      expectedValue.Append(@"</div>");
      result.ShouldEqual(expectedValue.ToString());

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little wonky to have a

```
public int PageNumbersToShow { get; set; }
```

Then do all dis bizness in the toString() method

```
if (TotalPages <= PageNumbersToShow) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++) {
      finalString.Append(new PageNumber(i, (SelectedItem == i)).ToString());
    }

  }
```

You've created a class to encapsulate a PageNumber. It would make more sense to have the Pager hold a list of these.

If you're thinking along these lines already, then a Pager is really just a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) of PageNumbers.

Don't do so much business logic processing in your toString() methods and constructors. Most of that logic should be in utility methods devoted to their particular tasks. For example

```
 if (Current) {
      span.AddCssClass("current");
      return span.ToString();
    } else {

      if (span.ToString().Contains("dots")) {
        return span.ToString();
      }
```

1. What if I wanna add another CSS class later?
2. What if I decide to change from  to

   like a reasonable person?

   What if I wanna add javascript events?

Answer (score 4):

instead of this malarky....

```
finalString.Append(new PageNumber(TotalPages).ToString());
```

why not something that manages the pagenumbering so you have a simple interface...

```
pages.AddPage(pageNumber);
```

and

```
pages.AddPage(2).Select();
```

then at the end...

```
finalString = pages.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using something like below paired with a separate html rendering helper method.  I thought it was pretty clean but I'm sure it's not perfect.

```
#region IPagedList

/// <remarks>
/// Represents a subset of a collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index and containing metadata about the superset collection of objects this subset was created from.
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object the collection should contain.</typeparam>
/// <seealso cref="IList{T}"/>
public interface IPagedList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Total number of subsets within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Total number of subsets within the superset.
    /// </value>
    int PageCount { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Total number of objects contained within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Total number of objects contained within the superset.
    /// </value>
    int TotalItemCount { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Zero-based index of this subset within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Zero-based index of this subset within the superset.
    /// </value>
    int PageIndex { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum size any individual subset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Maximum size any individual subset.
    /// </value>
    int PageSize { get; }
}

#endregion

#region PagedList

/// <summary>
/// Represents a subset of a collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index and containing metadata about the superset collection of objects this subset was created from.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object the collection should contain.</typeparam>
/// <seealso cref="IPagedList{T}"/>
/// <seealso cref="List{T}"/>
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default CTOR
    /// </summary>
    public PagedList()
        : this(new List<T>(), 0, 0, 20)
    { }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of a type deriving from <see cref="BasePagedList{T}"/> and sets properties needed to calculate position and size data on the subset and superset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index of the subset of objects contained by this instance.</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">The maximum size of any individual subset.</param>
    /// <param name="totalItemCount">The size of the superset.</param>
    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> list, int totalItemCount, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        : base(list == null ? new List<T>() : list)      
    {
        if (pageIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", pageIndex, "PageIndex cannot be below 0.");
        if (pageSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageSize", pageSize, "PageSize cannot be less than 1.");

        // set source to blank list if superset is null to prevent exceptions
        this.PageCount = CalcNumberOfPages(totalItemCount, pageSize);
        this.TotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the number of pages in a set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="totalItemCount">Total number of items in the set</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">Number of items in a page</param>
    /// <returns>Number of pages (int).</returns>
    protected int CalcNumberOfPages(int totalItemCount, int pageSize)
    {
        return (totalItemCount % pageSize == 0) ? (totalItemCount / pageSize) : totalItemCount / pageSize + 1;
    }


    #region IPagedList<T> Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Total number of subsets within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    public int PageCount { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Total number of objects contained within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    public int TotalItemCount { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Zero-based index of this subset within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    public int PageIndex { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum size any individual subset.
    /// </summary>
    public int PageSize { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if this is the first subset within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsFirstPage
    {
        get { return PageIndex < 1; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if this is the last subset within the superset.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsLastPage
    {
        get { return PageIndex + 1 == PageCount; }
    }

    #endregion
}

#endregion

#region Extensions

/// <summary>
/// Container for extension methods designed to simplify the creation of instances of <see cref="PagedList{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Container for extension methods designed to simplify the creation of instances of <see cref="PagedList{T}"/>.
/// </remarks>
public static class PagedListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a subset of this collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index and containing metadata about the collection of objects the subset was created from.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object the collection should contain.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="superset">The collection of objects to be divided into subsets. If the collection implements <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/>, it will be treated as such.</param>
    /// <param name="index">The index of the subset of objects to be contained by this instance.</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">The maximum size of any individual subset.</param>
    /// <returns>A subset of this collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index and containing metadata about the collection of objects the subset was created from.</returns>
    /// <seealso cref="PagedList{T}"/>
    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int totalItemCount, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(list, totalItemCount, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}

public static class PageQuery
{
    public static PagedList<T> Paginate<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalItemCount)
    {
        return query.Skip(Math.Max(pageSize * pageIndex, 0)).Take(pageSize).ToPagedList(totalItemCount, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}

#endregion
```

Then to page a dataset with Linq to SQL you call it like:

```
        int rowCount = (from o in dc.Table
                        select o).Count();

        return (from o in dc.Table
                orderby o.LastName
                select o).Paginate(pageNum, pageSize, rowCount);
```

Then to render the pager html something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Renders a paging control.  This has to be used in strongly typed pages that use PagedList<Entity>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    /// <param name="routeName"></param>
    /// <param name="routeValues"></param>
    public static void Pager<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> page, string routeName, object routeValues) where T : class, IPagedList
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeDictionary = (routeValues == null) ? new RouteValueDictionary() : new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(page.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Output);

        if (writer != null)
        {
            int lowerBound = (page.ViewData.Model.PageIndex) - 10;
            lowerBound = lowerBound < 0 ? 0 : lowerBound;

            int upperBound = (page.ViewData.Model.PageIndex) + 10;
            upperBound = upperBound > page.ViewData.Model.PageCount ? page.ViewData.Model.PageCount : upperBound;

            writer.Write("<div class=\"pager\">");

            string pageNumberParam;

            for (int pageNum = lowerBound + 1; pageNum <= upperBound; pageNum++)
            {
                pageNumberParam = string.Empty;

                if (pageNum != page.ViewData.Model.PageIndex + 1)
                {
                    VirtualPathData vPathData = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(page.ViewContext.RequestContext, routeName, routeDictionary);

                    pageNumberParam += vPathData.VirtualPath.Contains('?') ? "&pageNum=" : "?pageNum=";
                    pageNumberParam += (pageNum - 1).ToString();

                    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, vPathData.VirtualPath + pageNumberParam);
                    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Alt, "Page " + pageNum);
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
                }

                writer.AddAttribute(
                    HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class,
                    pageNum == page.ViewData.Model.PageIndex + 1 ? "pageLinkCurrent" : "pageLink"
                );

                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
                writer.Write(pageNum);
                writer.RenderEndTag();

                if (pageNum != page.ViewData.Model.PageIndex + 1)
                {
                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                }
                writer.Write(" ");
            }

            writer.Write("<br /> (");
            writer.Write(page.ViewData.Model.TotalItemCount);
            writer.Write(" items in ");
            writer.Write(page.ViewData.Model.PageCount);
            writer.Write(" pages) ");

            writer.Write("</div>");
        }

    }
```

I think a similar pattern was in the 2nd last issue of MSDN mag too...